# how to update multiple tables connected through HasMany relation

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.0

I have two tables. One is `menu` and the second table name is a `submenu`. `submenu` has the `menu_id` as a foreign key. I want to do a query like this:

```sql
UPDATE submenu SET active=1 WHERE menu_id = 8;
UPDATE menu SET active=1 WHERE id = 8;
```

I want to update multiple fields in a submenu and one field in menu table.

This is what I am doing. But it isn't working:

```
$this->loadModel("Menu");
$this->loadModel("SubMenu");

$active['active'] = 1;
$this->Menu->id = 8;
$this->Menu->SubMenu->saveAssociated($active);
```

Please let me know what I am doing wrong here

Comment: Read https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/saving-data.html & https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/saving-data.html#bulk-updates

Answer (score 0):

```
$data = [
    'title' => 'First Post',
    'comments' => [
        ['body' => 'Best post ever'],
        ['body' => 'I really like this.']
    ]
];
$articles = TableRegistry::get('Articles');
$article = $articles->newEntity($data, [
    'associated' => ['Comments']
]);
$articles->save($article);
```

Comment: OP added the cakephp-2.0 tag, this is cake 3.